# How do I distribute CiviSurvey by email, and then analyze the results?

Tags: civireport, civisurvey, civipetiton

Can somebody help me to answer these following questions or refer me to some source to find out the answer:

1. I've created a survey by creating the custom fields and custom data. How do I get this survey distributed to people on my database i.e how do I email the survey link to targeted respondents?
2. If the survey can be emailed to them, are their answers automatically recorded on their account/profile?
3. In the report feature we can see answers of individual respondents. But does civiSurvey provide analysis capabilities such as counting percentage of the people choosing a, b, c for a specific question? If yes, where do we get that information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you're putting together a survey, the CiviCRM tool you'll want to use is the Profile.  Create a new profile with the custom fields along with any standard ones you want to include.

You'll then want to send an email with an automatically-personalized link to the profile--that way, everyone's responses will go on his or her own contact record without having to log in.  The full directions are here (follow the directions for Profile): https://aghstrategies.com/content/how-create-one-click-personalized-links-civicrm-emails

The analysis capabilities in CiviCRM reports are kind of crude, but you'll be able to export the results into a spreadsheet and do any kind of statistics you need.

A note about "surveys": this use case is collecting information into custom fields on the contact record, so that's a natural use for a profile in "edit" mode.  There is a feature in CiviCampaign called "survey" that is oriented toward collecting information through phone interviews or door-knocking.  You'll have the fields on the contact and/or the activity, and interviewers will fill it in.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Hunt for your very useful answer.
I've created custom fields in the custom data and tried setting up Profile, but I cannot find those custom fields in the drop-down list of Field Name when I'm trying to add fields in the profile.

Comment: You probably have the wrong entity type--contacts, individuals, activities, etc.--for the field you're trying to include.